# Custom API in Azure APP Serivce examples searched for Android Client

Tags: android, api, azure, controller

I need a working example for a custom API for Microsoft Azure App Service. 
I could not get any useful or working information/examples for that, or they just show each time different approaches which are outdated?!?!
For now I have a working table controller which gets information from database and returns it back to my Android client. Now I need to define a custom API Controller to get a string back. In the examples they  are all sending an object to the service in order to get an object back. I do not want to send anything to the API, just retrieve some information back from a GET Request.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// EDIT - Added / edited client / server code to Post a String.

You can use the following code to do a GET request on the auto generated API controller Visual Studio creates (ValuesController).

```
private void getStringFromAzure() throws MalformedURLException {

    // Create the MobileService Client object and set your backend URL
    String yourURL = "https://yourApp.azurewebsites.net/";
    MobileServiceClient mClient = new MobileServiceClient(yourURL, this);

    // Your query pointing to yourURL/api/values
    ListenableFuture<JsonElement> query = mClient.invokeApi("values", null, GetMethod, null);

    // Callback method
    Futures.addCallback(query, new FutureCallback<JsonElement>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JsonElement jsonElement) {

            // You are expecting a String you can just output the result.
            final String result = jsonElement.toString();

            // Since you are on a async task, you need to show the result on the UI thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + throwable.getMessage());
        }
    });
}

public void sendString(final String someString) throws MalformedURLException {

        // Your query pointing to /api/values/{String}
        ListenableFuture<JsonElement> query = mClient.invokeApi("values/" + someString, null, PostMethod, null);

        // Callback method
        Futures.addCallback(query, new FutureCallback<JsonElement>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(JsonElement jsonElement) {

                // You are expecting a String you can just output the result.
                final String result = jsonElement.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) { }
        });
}
```

The backend API: (ValuesController)

```
{
    // Use the MobileAppController attribute for each ApiController you want to use  
    // from your mobile clients 
    [MobileAppController]
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/values
        public string Get()
        {
            return "Hello World!";
        }

        // POST api/values/inputString
        public string Post(string inputString)
        {
            return inputString;
        }
    }
}
```

You can also send parameters along in the following way:

```
List<Pair<String, String>> parameters = new ArrayList<>();

parameters.add(new Pair<>("name", "John"));
parameters.add(new Pair<>("password", "fourwordsalluppercase"));

ListenableFuture<JsonElement> query = client.invokeApi("yourAPI", PostMethod, parameters);
```

Or as json in the body:

```
JsonObject body = new JsonObject();

body.addProperty("currentPassword", currentPassword);
body.addProperty("password", password);
body.addProperty("confirmPassword", confirmPassword);

ListenableFuture<JsonElement> query = mClient.invokeApi("yourAPI", body, PostMethod, null);
```

Comment: Thanks again for your solution. Is there a way to provide me a working sample for a "Post" method in which I can pass a String and the Backend API receives it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: No problem! :]
I added the code to send a String and two other ways of sending data to the backend. I did not test the code though.. 
Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much! I meantime I solved it, but it took me 2 days figuring out :D The problem was more on the server side regarding Azure mobile Service custom API and how it is receiving that string and how to parse it.

Comment: My expertise is more on the Android side then backend, so I am a bit worried posting code without being able to test it properly (since I am still on holiday). ;) 
Good you solved it!

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, I think there are two parts in your question which include as below. And I think you can separately refer to two sections to get the answers and write your own example.

1. *How to define a custom API on Azure Mobile App to retrieve data from database?*  Please refer to the section [`Custom APIs`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#CustomAPI) to know how to do with Azure Mobile App backend.
2. *How to call a custom API from Android App?* Please refer to the section [`How to: Call a custom API`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library/#custom-api) to know how to do with Android SDK.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your information. I already know that documentation and that´s the problem. There is no real example given, only 2 lines of code. (see: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/ ;   How to: Define a custom API controller; Step 4). 

I need a real example for a GET Request and also the API call for that specific GET Request for Android without passing any object to the request. I want to get a string back to my Android App.